# How to do a simple array search in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I need to know if an integer exists in an array of integers.

Here's what I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytest1 () RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $fun$
DECLARE
    testid              INTEGER := 22;
    testary             INTEGER [] := '{1,2,3}';
BEGIN
    PERFORM testid = ANY (testary);
    IF FOUND THEN
        RAISE NOTICE '@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ found:';
    END IF;
    RETURN 1;
END;
$fun$
```

It always returns true. This should be so simple I feel ashamed asking for help. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can resolve the issue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytest1 () RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $fun$
DECLARE
    testid              INTEGER := 1;
    testary             INTEGER [] := '{1,2,3}';
BEGIN
    IF testid = ANY (testary::INTEGER[]) THEN
        RETURN 1;
    END IF;
    RETURN 0;
END;
$fun$;


SELECT mytest1();
```

Comment: This is so simple I'm ashamed I did not figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can be simpler, yet:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytest1()
  RETURNS boolean AS
$func$
DECLARE
   testid  int := 1;
   testary int[] := '{1,2,3}';
BEGIN
   RETURN (testid = ANY(testary));
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

The expression returns a `boolean` value which can be returned directly.